# Three dimensional datasets

Tags: python, h5py

I'm writing data into a three dimensional dataset and I've noticed a very disturbing problem. I want to write 20 matrix of 2000x2000 into the dataset. I noticed that writing into a dataset of 2000x2000x20 is insanely slower than writing into a dataset of 20x2000x2000.
Does anyone have an idea about why?

Slow - time:66.4123821259

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file1 = h5py.File('/home/serra/Documents/Software/Store_testdata/TestDataset.h5')
a = file1.create_group('run')
b = a.create_dataset('seq_1',(2000,2000,20))

for i in range(20):
    b[:,:,i] = np.random.rand(2000,2000)

file1.close()
```

Fast - time:3.72713208199

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file1 = h5py.File('/home/serra/Documents/Software/Store_testdata/TestDataset.h5')
a = file1.create_group('run')
b = a.create_dataset('seq_1',(20,2000,2000))

for i in range(20):
    b[i,:,:] = np.random.rand(2000,2000)

file1.close()
```

Comment: I think this has to do with the way processors are made. There are certain advantages to iterating over rows then columns. I think this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance difference is not related to the sizes of the matrices, but to the order in which you fill the data:

```
b[i,:,:] = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
b[:,:,i] = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
```

In the first case, you are filling cells that are contiguous in memory. In the second case, cells are scattered across memory.

When items are in contiguous memory, all neighbour cells will probably be cached when the first of them is fetched. In the other case, when one is fetched, most of its neighboring cells that will be kept in cache will not be used.

For ilustration purposes, let's consider the two-dimensional case, and let's assume that two items fit in cache.  The following matrix:

```
numpy.array('[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]]')
```

is stored like this in memory:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60
```

Let's see what happens when we iterate over it in row order:

```
a[0][0] → fetch 10 from memory (cached: 10 20)
a[0][1] → read 20 from cache
a[0][2] → fetch 30 from memory (cached: 30 40)
a[1][0] → read 40 from cache
a[1][1] → fetch 50 from memory (cached: 50 60)
a[1][2] → read 60 from cache
```

Now, let's iterate in column order:

```
a[0][0] → fetch 10 from memory (cached: 10 20)
a[1][0] → fetch 40 from memory (cached: 30 40)
a[2][1] → fetch 20 from memory (cached: 10 20)
a[0][1] → fetch 50 from memory (cached: 50 60)
a[1][2] → fetch 30 from memory (cached: 30 40)
a[1][2] → fetch 60 from memory (cached: 50 60)
```

So, in the first case, you can iterate over the whole matrix using only three memory accesses, and in the second case, you need six. As a rule of thumb, reading a value from memory is ~200 times slower than reading it from cache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have any idea of where I can find information about cells position in memory?

Comment: @bserra: In Numpy, the cells are stored row-wise by default, i.e. in this order: a[0,0,0], a[0,0,1], a[0,0,2]..., but you can change it to column-wise: `numpy.array('[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]', order='F')`.

Comment: Wikipedia discusses it at [Row-major_order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason why it is faster when you are writing into a dataset of 20x2000x2000 is because there are less comparisons and increment/decrements being done. Think of it as a for loop just like the following (2000x2000x20):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
        {
            dataset[i][j][k] = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Number of comparison operations: 88,004,001

Number of increment operations: 84,002,000

While in the next loop (20x2000x2000):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 2000; k++)
        {
            dataset[i][j][k] = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Number of comparison operations:80,040,020

Number of increment operations: 80,080,041

Thanks to this handy function I made because of this link http://umencs.blogspot.com/2013/04/optimization-of-nested-for-loops.html

```
void ComparisonAndIncrementCount(int nOuterLoop, int nMiddleLoop, int nInnerLoop)
{
    int nComparisonCount = 0;
    int nIncrementCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; (++nComparisonCount) && i < nOuterLoop; i++, ++nIncrementCount)
    {
        for (int j = 0; (++nComparisonCount) && j < nMiddleLoop; j++, ++nIncrementCount)
        {
            for (int k = 0; (++nComparisonCount) && k < nInnerLoop; k++, ++nIncrementCount) {}
        }
    }

    printf("\n#No. of Increment Operations of Nested For Loop: %d", nIncrementCount);
    printf("\n#No. of Comparison Operations of Nested For Loop: %d", nComparisonCount);
}
```